# Find enums listed in Python DESCRIPTOR for ProtoBuf

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I have received a Google ProtoBuf using Python, and am attempting to compare the value for an enum to a string representation of it. Based on [this](http://nongraphical.com/2013/12/how-to-match-protobuf-enum-constants-with-values-in-python/) and [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class) I should be able to use something like `enum_values_by_name` to get the info I need. However, all the `enum*` related attributes are empty:

```
>>> type(my_message)
<class 'myObjects_pb2.myObject'>

>>> my_message
# nID: 53564
# nAge: 2
# type: OBJECT_CLASS_SIGN
# view: OBJECT_VIEW_FRONT   

>>> my_message.type
# 1

>>> filter(lambda s: s.startswith('enum'), dir(my_message.DESCRIPTOR))
# ['enum_types', 'enum_types_by_name', 'enum_values_by_name']

>>> my_message.DESCRIPTOR.enum_types
# []

>>> my_message.DESCRIPTOR.enum_types_by_name
# {}

>>> my_message.DESCRIPTOR.enum_values_by_name
# {}
```

Perhaps it is related to the fact that my protobuf is defined in many files, and the enums I want are not defined in the main file which I'm importing (but which is used to decode `my_message`)?

Why am I getting these empty collections and (more importantly) how do find information about the enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the `DESCRIPTOR` for the message includes enum attributes that are not populated. (This seems like a bug to me.) However, there are (at least) two solutions to this:

1) If you know the name of the file where the enums are defined, you can 'hack' get the enum value by name via:

```
# This is the root ProtoBuf definition
from mydir import rootapi_pb2 

# We happen to know that the enums are defined in myenums.proto
enum_file = rootapi_pb2.myenums__pb2 # NOTE: Extra Underscore!
enum_value = getattr(enum_file, 'OBJECT_CLASS_SIGN')
```

If you don't want to rely on this hack, however, you can eventually find the enum descriptor, and thus the value from the name, via:

```
my_message.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name['type'].enum_type.values_by_name['OBJECT_CLASS_SIGN'].number
```

Because that's so horrific, here it is wrapped up as a safe, re-usable function:

```
def enum_value(msg, field_name, enum_name):
    """Return the integer for the enum name of a field,
       or None if the field does not exist, is not an enum, or the
       enum does not have a value with the supplied name."""
    field = msg.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.get(field_name,None)
    if field and field.enum_type:
        enum = field.enum_type.values_by_name.get(enum_name,None)
        return enum and enum.number

print(enum_value(my_message, 'type', 'OBJECT_CLASS_SIGN'))
# 1
```

Comment: _Editorial: It says a lot about the Python language and ProtoBuf API design that the correct way to get information is often so cumbersome and verbose that you basically need to write a function to accomplish your goals. IMHO the Python community seems not to value pragmatism and convenience (at least compared to other, similar languages)._

Comment: judging the python language by the ProtoBuf API implementation is quite odd... I'm not sure I've ever worked with any python library that was as terrible as the ProtoBug API for python...

Answer (score 1):

ProtoBuf for python is super ugly...but I had to use it anyway...

I feel like the function by @Phrogz could be simplified a bit. This is the function I've came with:

```
def get_enum_name_by_number(parent, field_name):
    field_value = getattr(parent, field_name)
    return parent.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name[field_name].enum_type.values_by_number.get(field_value).name

print(my_message.type)
# 1
print(get_enum_name_by_number(my_message, 'type'))
# OBJECT_CLASS_SIGN
```

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, if you want to go in the opposite direction, from int value to key in a protobuf enum I've been using this:

```py
def lookup_template_name(template_id: int) -> str:
    """Lookup the template name from the template id"""

    try:
        return notify.EmailTemplate.Name(template_id)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error looking up template name: {e}")
        return e
```

```
logger.info(f"Template name is: {lookup_template_name(1)}")

# 2022-11-23 16:04:11:977 INFO Template name is: EMAIL_TEMPLATE_WELCOME_EMAIL
```

```
logger.info(f"Template name is: {lookup_template_name(123456)}")

# 2022-11-23 16:04:50:334 ERROR Error looking up template name: Enum EmailTemplate has no name defined for value 123456
```

The only issue is that you need to already know the name of the enum (in this case `EmailTemplate`)